# "places where something is" vs. "places ∅ something is" vs. "places ∅ something is in"

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis

> 1. I've been a few places gang wars were prevalent.
> 2. I've been a few places gang wars were prevalent **in**.
> 3. I've been a few places **where** gang wars were prevlant.

I've seen people use **place(s)** both with and without a preposition, still the first example sounds a tad weird, which is why I post this question. Is the first sentence grammatically correct? If so, can we drop these prepositions anytime we want, or does it always depend on the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third sentence is normal, with *where* acting as a relative ([this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns) describes it as "informal", but I'm not sure I agree).

Your second sentence is normal, with the relative pronoun *which* omitted, as it regularly can be if it is not the subject of the relative clause.

Your first sentence is not grammatical in standard Englishes, but I have certainly heard it in various non-standard dialects. To me (British) it has an American flavour (but still non-standard).